# Buttons are getting overlap

Tags: iphone, ios6, uibutton

I m a newbie in ios development , recently i've start creating simple calculator, but i m facing some real problems when i run this app on simulator . My buttons get over lap where as in .xib they are far away with each other . when to solve this thing i relocate buttons at more distance , text got shrink or hides .

Pictures will clear my problem[image: This the problem which im facing and these three screen shots are the behavior of problem which is arising when im relocating my buttons :S Please help i've tried alot :S]

FYI : My simulator version is 6.0 and xcode version is 4.5.2 !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, a new project in Xcode 4.5.2 uses *Autolayout*. To turn this off, select the .xib file, use the File inspector, and uncheck "Use Autolayout". This will keep your subviews from jumping around when the superview is resized in the interface (as it is when it loads initially, and when rotating).

Eventually you'll need to learn about autolayout (and autoresizing, and layout in general):

http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch14.html#_layout

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer + learning stuff . Thank you :)